# Sort autocomplete suggestions by first letter alphabetical

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sort autocomplete suggestions by first letter alphabetical.

Now it look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5jDP.png

If i type letter C i want to show tag suggestions like this:

- C
- C++
- Active Directory
- Apple Script
- BlueCoat

Code:

```
$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM autocomplete WHERE name LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$json = '[';
$first = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
    $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['name'].'"}';
}
$json .= ']';

echo $json;
```

I hope someone could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: if the `name` field contains special characters such as " and /, your JSON output will be broken. Better use `json_encode` to create JSON in PHP!

Comment: `Alexander` answer will do the trick.

Comment: I don't think that it is a matter of MySQL query.

Comment: Yes thats correct @Cristik

Comment: But C is greater than A...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need

```
SELECT * 
FROM autocomplete 
WHERE name LIKE '%$text%' 
ORDER BY (name LIKE '$text%') DESC, 
         name ASC
```

The first ORDER BY clause is a BOOLEAN value that is `1` when name starts with `$text` and `0` otherwise, so when you sort by that in `DESC` order, values starting with `$text` will be moved to the front of the list (and those only containing it elsewhere will be moved to the end). The second clause then sorts both "sublists" alphabetically again.

Comment: Quite elegant solution as it only changes the SQL query!

Answer (score 1):

**Update.** As it seems that you need suggestions that start with the entered prefix to appear first in the list, you'll need to use a user-sorting function. I've updated the code to match this.

If you want to do the sort in PHP, you need to create an array with the results, and sort it via one the [PHP array sorting function](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). Here's your modified code that uses the `usort()` function:

```
$term = $_GET['term'];
$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($term);

$query = "SELECT * FROM autocomplete WHERE name LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$results = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $results[] = $row['name'];
}

usort($results, function($item1, $item2) use($term) {
    // prefixed items need to go first
    $item1HasPrefix = strpos($item1, $term) === 0;
    $item2HasPrefix = strpos($item2, $term) === 0;

    if($item1HasPrefix && $item2HasPrefix) {
        // if both items have the prefix, sort them
        return strcmp($item1, $item2);
    } elseif($item1HasPrefix) {
        return -1;
    } elseif($item2HasPrefix) {
        return 1;
    } else {
       return strcmp($item1, $item2);
    }
});

echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Most of the time, doing data processing in SQL is faster than doing it in PHP. I once inherited a PHP script that needed an hour for execution on the production dataset in a postgreSQL database (my predecessor told me with pride that he got it down from 6 hours). Replacing the 200 LoC with a single INSERT ... SELECT statement (with a length of about 7k characters), I got the very same things done in three minutes.

Comment: @Alexander: yes, I agree with you, however due to the custom sorting the OP needs, with terms that begin with the search to be returned first I'm not sure about an SQL approach

Comment: Yes i used the latest code, but i think @Alexander code is more effective. Because it does not make the code bigger? Is that not correct?

Comment: If Alexander's query gives the results in the order you need, then definitively his solution is the way to go. Less code means less bugs/headaches/etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can try **bootstrap-typeahead** JS autocomplete library in Client Side.

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Don't do this, at least try to brief your answer here. What will happen, if you remove your git later.